# Не работает правильно перегрузка оператора << для класса одномерного динамического массива в C++

Tags: c++, linux, выделение-памяти, valgrind

Хочу реализовать класс динамического одномерного массива самостоятельно, через указатель.
Код:

```
// program.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
// For rand(), srand()
#include <cstdlib>
// For time()
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

class Dynamic_Array {
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, const Dynamic_Array & an_array);
public:
    Dynamic_Array(int elements = 2);
    ~Dynamic_Array();
    void fill_random();
    void shuffle_random();
    int search_diff_nums();
private:
    double * m_p_array;
    int m_size;
public:
    const int UP_LIMIT = 50;
    const int LOW_LIMIT = -50;
private:
    int search_equal_nums();
};

Dynamic_Array::Dynamic_Array(int elements)
{
    m_p_array = new double[elements];
    m_size = elements;
}

Dynamic_Array::~Dynamic_Array()
{
    delete [] m_p_array;
}

void Dynamic_Array::fill_random()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_size; ++i)
    {
        // Generation of random numbers between LOW_LIMIT and UP_LIMIT.
        m_p_array[i] = rand() % (UP_LIMIT - LOW_LIMIT + 1) + LOW_LIMIT;
    }
}

void Dynamic_Array::shuffle_random()
{
    int i = 0;
    int index_1, index_2;

    while (i < m_size)
    {
        index_1 = rand() % m_size;
        index_2 = rand() % m_size;
        
        if (index_1 == index_2)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            double temp = m_p_array[index_1];
            m_p_array[index_1] = m_p_array[index_2];
            m_p_array[index_2] = temp;
        }
        ++i;
    }
}

int Dynamic_Array::search_diff_nums()
{
    return m_size - search_equal_nums();
}

int Dynamic_Array::search_equal_nums()
{
    // Counter of equal numbers in the array.
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < m_size; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m_size; ++j)
        {
            if (m_p_array[i] == m_p_array[j] && i != j)
            {
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return count;
}

ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, const Dynamic_Array & an_array)
{
    os << "Array:\n";
    os << fixed << setprecision(2);
    for (int i = 0; i < an_array.m_size; ++i)
    {
        os << setw(5) << an_array.m_p_array[i];
    }
    os << endl;

    return os;
}

int main(void)
{
    Dynamic_Array an_array(20);
    cout << an_array << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Интересует прежде всего работа функции *main()*. Всё компилируется без  ошибок и предупреждений с флагом *-Wall*, но несмотря на это при прогоне программы через **valgrind** возникают утечки памяти. С чем они связаны, так и не понял. Прошу разъяснить этот момент.

Команда компиляции программы: *g++ program.cpp -Wall --pedantic*

Команда запуска программы **valgrind**: *valgrind ./a.out*

Тестировал на ОС Linux Mint 20.2 через CLI.
Вывод **valgrind**:

```
==16032== 
==16032== HEAP SUMMARY:
==16032==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16032==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 73,888 bytes allocated
==16032== 
==16032== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==16032== 
==16032== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==16032== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==16032== ERROR SUMMARY: 321 errors from 13 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: https://ideone.com/ds8WXo — работает. А всё ли вы нам рассказали? Может, делаете еще что-то, где играет роковую роль отсутствие копирующего конструктора и оператора присваивания?...

Comment: Приведенный в вопросе код не компилируется.

Comment: @user7860670 А так ли уж требуется выписывать все инклуды в вопросе?...

Comment: @Harry Несомненно. И инклюды, и версия компилятора, и команды компилятору, и команды valgrid, и лог происходящего.

Comment: Советую читать: https://pvs-studio.ru/ru/blog/posts/cpp/a0050/

Comment: @Harry, в данной программе копирующий конструктор и перегруженный оператор присваивания необязательны. Из эксперимента дописал их - не повлияло на вывод valgrind.
Версия компилятора: g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0

Comment: @user7860670, проблема в дружественной функции, так как если закомментирую строчку кода, отвечающую за вывод объекта на экран, то ошибок **valgrind** не выдаёт. Хочу выяснить, в каком месте кода этой функции я ошибаюсь. Прошу Вашего совета.

Comment: Протестировал программу, проблема была в том, что память была неинициализирована при создании нового объекта класса *Dynamical_Array*, то есть нужно было вызывать метод *fill_array()* перед отправкой объекта в *cout* - сделал так, утечек памяти нет. Но вот вопрос: разве неинициализированная память в куче является ошибкой, если указатель на неё имеется? Насколько мне известно, нет, то есть вывод должен отображать случайные значения, содержащиеся в куче на данный момент. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я заблуждаюсь.

Comment: Вот так всегда, пишут сначала *"при прогоне программы через valgrind возникают утечки памяти"*, а потом выясняется, что *"All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible"*. *"вывод должен отображать случайные значения, содержащиеся в куче на данный момент"* - Нет, чтение неинициализированной памяти является Неопределенным Поведением. Это грубая ошибка, которую, среди прочих, может отловить valgrind. И практически весь код в вопросе - лишний, достаточно было `int main(){ int x; int y{x}; }`

Answer (score 0):

Окончательный код:

```
// program.cpp
// 
// "Dynamic array" program.
// 
// Functionality:
// 1) constructor allocating memory for a given number of elements;
// 2) destructor;
// 3) copy constructor;
// 4) overloaded assignment operator; 
// 5) filling the array with random numbers;
// 6) shuffle of the array randomly;
// 7) search for the number of different elements;
// 8) displaying the array on the screen with cout object and << operator;
// Note: no use std::vector!!!
// 
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
// For rand(), srand()
#include <cstdlib>
// For time()
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

class Dynamic_Array {
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, const Dynamic_Array & an_array);
public:
    Dynamic_Array(int elements = 2);
    ~Dynamic_Array();
    Dynamic_Array(const Dynamic_Array & c);
    Dynamic_Array & operator=(const Dynamic_Array & c);
    void fill_random();
    void shuffle_random();
    int search_diff_nums();
private:
    double * m_p_array;
    int m_size;
public:
    const int UP_LIMIT = 50;
    const int LOW_LIMIT = -50;
private:
    int search_equal_nums();
};

Dynamic_Array::Dynamic_Array(int elements)
{
    m_p_array = new double[elements];
    m_size = elements;
}

Dynamic_Array::~Dynamic_Array()
{
    delete [] m_p_array;
}

Dynamic_Array::Dynamic_Array(const Dynamic_Array & c)
{
    m_p_array = new double[c.m_size];
    for (int i = 0; i < c.m_size; ++i)
    {
        m_p_array[i] = c.m_p_array[i];
    }
    m_size = c.m_size;
}

Dynamic_Array & Dynamic_Array::operator=(const Dynamic_Array & c)
{
    if (this != &c)
    {
        delete [] m_p_array;
        m_p_array = new double[c.m_size];
        for (int i = 0; i < c.m_size; ++i)
        {
            m_p_array[i] = c.m_p_array[i];
        }

        m_size = c.m_size;
    }

    return *this;
}

void Dynamic_Array::fill_random()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_size; ++i)
    {
        // Generation of random numbers between LOW_LIMIT and UP_LIMIT.
        m_p_array[i] = rand() % (UP_LIMIT - LOW_LIMIT + 1) + LOW_LIMIT;
    }
}

void Dynamic_Array::shuffle_random()
{
    int i = 0;
    int index_1, index_2;

    while (i < m_size)
    {
        index_1 = rand() % m_size;
        index_2 = rand() % m_size;
        
        if (index_1 == index_2)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            double temp = m_p_array[index_1];
            m_p_array[index_1] = m_p_array[index_2];
            m_p_array[index_2] = temp;
        }
        ++i;
    }
}

int Dynamic_Array::search_diff_nums()
{
    return m_size - search_equal_nums();
}

int Dynamic_Array::search_equal_nums()
{
    // Counter of equal numbers in the array.
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < m_size; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j != i && j < m_size; ++j)
        {
            if (m_p_array[i] == m_p_array[j])
            {
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return count;
}

ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, const Dynamic_Array & an_array)
{
    os << fixed << setprecision(2);
    for (int i = 0; i < an_array.m_size; ++i)
    {
        os << setw(10) << an_array.m_p_array[i];
    }
    os << endl;

    return os;
}

int main(void)
{
    // For fill_random() and shuffle_random() methods.
    srand(static_cast<unsigned>(time(0)));
    // Constructor is working.
    Dynamic_Array arr_1(20);
    arr_1.fill_random();

    // Copy constructor is working.
    Dynamic_Array arr_3 = arr_1;
    Dynamic_Array arr_2;
    // Overloaded assignment operator (method operator=()) is working.
    arr_2 = arr_1;

    cout << "Array 1:\n";
    // Friend function operator<<() is working.
    cout << arr_1 << endl;
    cout << "The number of different numbers is " << arr_1.search_diff_nums() << endl;
    
    cout << "\nSame array 2:\n";
    cout << arr_2 << endl;

    arr_3.shuffle_random();
    cout << "\nShuffled array 3 with same elements as array 1 and 2:\n";
    cout << arr_3 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Утечек памяти не было, о чём извещал **valgrind**, проблема была в том, что данная утилита определяет даже **чтение** неинициализированного фрагмента памяти кучи как ошибку, то есть использование недопустимого участка памяти. Посему сначала вызвал метод *fill_random()*, заполнив массив случайными значениями в указанном диапазоне, и только затем отправил его в *cout*. Добавил конструктор копирования и перегруженный оператор присваивания, так как об этом просили в комментариях, и хочу заметить, что там наполнение массива тоже необходимо предусмотреть, иначе появляются те же ошибки от **valgrind**'а.